# Add delay to print screen button in windows

Tags: windows

I want to keep using the `PrtScr` button to open Snipping Tool but I often touch it by accident.  I do not want to just disable it and have to use `Win + Shift + S`.  Can I somehow change the settings just for that one key to delay the acceptance of a click until its been held down for a full second?  Windows 11